# Expected value of linear momentum with real wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction

Let's suppose that a quantum system is characterized by a real wave function $\psi(x)$. How can I prove that in this case the expected value of the linear momentum $\mathbf{p}$ is zero, using the position representation?

I tried using the expression of this operator in the position representation, but I fail to see why the resulting integral has to equal zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite similar to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327575/what-can-we-infer-about-the-wave-function-from-the-fact-that-the-expectation-val?rq=1)

The expectation value is:

$$
\langle p\rangle = \frac{\hbar}{i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\ \psi^*(x)\frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x} \underbrace{=}_{\psi \ \mathrm{real}}   \frac{\hbar}{i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\ \psi(x)\frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}\
$$

The result then follows directly by integrating by parts (assuming $\psi$ vanishes at spatial infinity, as it must to be normalizable):
$$
\langle p \rangle = -\frac{\hbar}{i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\ \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial x}\psi(x)
$$
So that $\langle p\rangle = -\langle p \rangle$, which implies that $\langle p\rangle = 0$.

There are many other ways of seeing this. The first is that $p$ is a Hermitian operator, so the expectation value is necessarily real. As the integral is real, but there's a factor $\hbar/i$ in front, the integral must be zero.

An alternative way is to consider the Fourier decomposition of $\psi(x)$, which can only contain the $k = 0$ term if $\psi(x)$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2450496/870278), the derivative of an even function is odd, and the derivative of an odd function is even. The momentum operator in 1-D is
$$
\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x},
$$
so the expectation of the momentum is
$$
\langle p \rangle = -i\hbar\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x) \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}dx.
$$
The integrand must be odd, and the integral of an odd function over a domain $(-L,L)$ for any $L$ is zero.

Comment: What happens if $\psi(x)$ is neither even nor odd?

Comment: As long as $\psi(x)$ is infinitely differentiable, we can find a series expansion. This means that the product $\psi(x)\partial\psi/\partial x$ can be expanded into a sum of polynomial terms, which must be either even or odd, and so my argument holds. I can't think of a situation where a wavefunction wouldn't be even or odd, _and_ not differentiable - certainly not within an undergraduate class.